# JQplot spacing between bars?

Tags: jquery, jqplot, bar-chart

So i have a graph that contains some sample data (this is not the actual data, because then it will fill more than this page!)

```
 x      y
 3     foo;a
 4     foo;b
 5     bar;a
 6     bar;b
```

[image]

now when i group the data into series, to make more sense of the graph like this

```
  x1       x2        y
  3        0        foo;a
  4        0        foo;b
  0        5        bar;a
  0        6        bar;b
```

[image]

As you can see, there is spacing between the bars for whatever reason. The general trend is the same, but with spacing. How can I remove the spacing?

here is a framework of my plot code

```
   title: some title,
    seriesDefaults: {
        renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
        shadow: false,        
        rendererOptions: {
            fillToZero: true,
            highlightColors: "#000000",
            shadowOffset: 0,
            shadowDepth: 0,
            barPadding: 0
        },
        pointLabels: {
            show: false
        }
    },
    grid: {
        shadow: false
    },
    highlighter: {
        showMarker: false,
        tooltipAxes: 'xy',
        showTooltip: true,
        show: true
    },
    axes: {
        xaxis: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
            ticks: tick[i],
            tickOptions: {
                angle: -90,
                fontSize: '0pt',
                showMark: false,
                showGridline: true
            }
        },
        yaxis: {
            label: "Norm",
            tickInterval: 1
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [jQplot documentation](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-barRenderer-js.html) about barRenderer, I think you can use **barPadding** and **barMargin** options to specify your needed space value (0px?)

**Edit** : barMargin seems to be what you needed as it allows you to specify number of pixels between **groups of bars** at adjacent axis values. (while barPadding allows you to specify number of pixels between adjacent bars at the same axis value).

Comment: in series Defaults, renderer options i have barMargin to 0, did not work. I set it to -20, seemed to work, but not really